# Devise is not holding on to a field I have added

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to add the field "name" to devise for login credentials, and devise required it upon sign up, but when that same user signs in it will take any name, indicating to me that it isn't holding on to and requiring the same name they used to sign up.

This is what I have so far...

**application_controller**

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit({ roles: [] }, :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation) }

  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
end
```

**edit and new registrations and new sessions**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %>
</div><br/>
```

And this was all after `rails g migration AddValueToUsers name:string` and then `rake db:migrate`

Am I missing a step?

Comment: I don't quite really understand this part `that same user signs in it will take any name`, is name used in user sign in? Or the name isn't saved after signup?

Comment: Did you configure name as a login key?  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address